# Hybris - ItemType of Relation concept

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Lately I have come across instances where people have itemtypes of a relation. Could someone please explain me the concept of this structure?

Also I have generated a relation, but am unable to find getters/setters for this. I believe, this is because no classes are generated for a relation.

For a specific project requirement I had to add a collection of relations to another Model, but could not find the setters and getters generated even for the collection, I think because the elementtype is a relation. I also checked the extensionmanager, but no getters and setters were generated there either.

Could someone please let me know if with such a structure I could getters and setters for collection of relations?

Thanks,
Farhan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should use `Relation` instead of `Collection` whenever it's possible. In hybris `Collection` stores the values as CSV in one field, hence it's limited by the max size of a field and it may be truncated.

Then for `Relation`, you won't have a Java model generated, but only a specific DB table.
The getter and setter will actually be generated in the target and source model depending on your cardinality.

If we take an example - `EmailMessage2ToAddressesRel`

```
    <relation code="EmailMessage2ToAddressesRel" .... >
        .
        .
        .
        <sourceElement type="EmailMessage" qualifier="toMessages"
            cardinality="many" collectiontype="list" />
        <targetElement type="EmailAddress" qualifier="toAddresses"
            cardinality="many" collectiontype="list" />
    </relation>
```

It map `many` `toMessages` as source to `many` `toAddresses` as target.

If you look at `EmailMessageModel` and `EmailAddressModel` you will find respectively the getter and setter for `toAddresses` and `toMessages`.

Comment: Thank you Alain for the perfect explanation!! I have a specific case, for e.g. i have added EmailMessage2ToAddressesRel as a collection in a another type say CustomerModel. How can i associate EmailMessage2ToAddressesRel to CustomerModel through as no getters or setters are generated at CustomerModel for populating the collection.

Comment: @Farhan You should probably just link the EmailMessage collection or Address collection in your customer. Then you will be able to retrieve the related elements with exinsting getter and setter on those classes.